# Mongoose error connecting to db

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

*Update: This problem is solved. I did vagrant ssh - node app.js and by coincidence let it be for like five to ten minutes. When I came back there had been result for the first time. Now it works every time normally, I don't know what the deal was.*

I realize this problem probably stems from a lack of basic knowledge about mongoDB and Mongoose, but I really can't find an answer to it. Even if I try to read basic documentation. Hopefully my problem is some silly simple thing I haven't thought of...

Every time I run node app.js, I get a message that Express is up and running listening on port 8000, shortly followed by "*Error connecting to mongoDB*". (I'm using a vagrant machine with Node, Express and mongoDB.) So localhost:8000 should at least give me some result, but there's no server found at all.

I did get it to work a few weeks ago, and I remember I had to do a *vagrant up - vagrant ssh - mongo - use todoDB* and then *node app.js*. If I exited the mongo shell and vagrant ssh logon, it stopped working. Since I'm a bit confused about mongoDB in general it seemed weird to me. I realize you have to get the vagrant machine up and running but I thought the db would be created and used as soon as my connection specifies the name of the db.

Now, regardless if I do a *vagrant ssh - mongo - use todoDB* before running the app, I dont get any result at all on localhost. I haven't changed anything.

Would really appreciate some insight to what the problem might be.

Full code below.

```
// config/database.js
dbConfig.connectionString: "mongodb://localhost/todoDB"




// libs/dbHelper.js
let mongoose = require("mongoose");

module.exports = {
    initialize : function() {

      let dbConfig = require("../config/database.js");

      let db = mongoose.connection;

      db.on("error", function() {
        console.log("Error connecting to mongoDB.");
      });

      db.once("open", function() {
          console.log("Succesfully connected to mongoDB.");
      });

      process.on("SIGINT", function() {
          db.close(function() {
              console.log("Mongoose connection disconnected through app termination.");
              process.exit(0);
          });
      });

      mongoose.connect(dbConfig.connectionString);
  }
};




// app.js
"use strict";

let express = require("express");
let bodyParser = require("body-parser");
let exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
let path = require("path");

let app = express();
let port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

require("./libs/dbHelper").initialize();

app.engine(".hbs", exphbs({
    defaultLayout: "main",
    extname: ".hbs"
}));
app.set("view engine", ".hbs");

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use("/", require("./routes/home.js"));
app.use("/", require("./routes/todo.js"));

app.use(function(request, response, next) {
    response.status(404).send("error/404");
});

app.use(function(error, request, response, next) {
    console.log(error.stack);
    response.status(500).send("Something broke");
});

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Express app listening on port %s!", port);
});
```

Comment: identify what ports are active ... in a terminal issue this ... sudo netstat -peanut

Comment: Thanks, this was a step in the right direction. I changed the port and now the app is working (localhost shows a result) even when I change it back to 8000. But the connecting error to mongoDB is still in effect.

Comment: from the command line confirm you mongo database server is running ... issue ... mongo   ... which will jump you into the mongo shell ... then get into the correct database finally issue a select on one of your documents to confirm your mongo is up and runing

Comment: Hm now when I do a show dbs there's only admin and local. I do use todoDB and show dbs again, there's still only admin and local. I'm not sure what you mean by selecting a document, but I haven't seeded the database so there's nothing in it. I'm trying to do a todo-app and I'll fill the db with notes vis a html form (once I get it working).

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

`dbConfig.connectionString: "mongodb://localhost/todoDB"`

with

`dbConfig.connectionString: "mongodb://localhost:27017/todoDB"`

27017 is the default port, so if you have mongo running on a different port you set yourself, change it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. It didn't help. Changing the port gave the effect that the site is showing on localhost now. But there is still a connection error.

Comment: Should I do the 'vagrant ssh - mongo - use todoDB' every time I launch the app? Also, a few weeks ago after I did these steps I remember I was still logged on to the machine via vagrant ssh when I did the 'node app.js' command. But now nothing happends when I try that when logged in.

Comment: Do you have `mongod` running in the background? That is required to make MongoDB accessible to the Express app. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/

Comment: Well I use a vagrant machine with mongoDB so I guess so. Not really sure how the vagrant machine is configurated, I'm to much of a beginner for that. When I try to run mongod it asks if a mongod instance might already be running.